# Clean way to launch the web browser from shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, standards, standards-compliance

In a bash script, I need to launch the user web browser. There seems to be many ways of doing this:

- `$BROWSER`
- `xdg-open`
- `gnome-open` on GNOME
- `www-browser`
- `x-www-browser`
- ...

Is there a more-standard-than-the-others way to do this that would work on most platforms, or should I just go with something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -n $BROWSER ]; then
  $BROWSER 'http://wwww.google.com'
elif which xdg-open > /dev/null; then
  xdg-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null; then
  gnome-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
# elif bla bla bla...
else
  echo "Could not detect the web browser to use."
fi
```

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me

Comment: Yep, although I'd swap xdg-open and gnome-open

Comment: Be careful about your URLs. It's easy to get a character like `?` or `&` in there that need to be quoted.

Comment: You should be able to drop the `eval` (it's a security risk): `$BROWSER http://wwww.google.com`

Comment: There's also `sensible-browser`.

Comment: I came here wanting a command for use in git bash (Windows). I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35811643/552067) `start` is what I want.

Comment: The answer [SHELL script to open a URL](//stackoverflow.com/a/46751980) gives command for Windows  `start https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`xdg-open` is standardized and should be available in most distributions.

Otherwise:

1. `eval` is evil, don't use it.
2. Quote your variables.
3. Use the correct test operators in the correct way.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if which xdg-open > /dev/null
then
  xdg-open URL
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null
then
  gnome-open URL
fi
```

Maybe this version is slightly better (still untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1
[[ -x $BROWSER ]] && exec "$BROWSER" "$URL"
path=$(which xdg-open || which gnome-open) && exec "$path" "$URL"
echo "Can't find browser"
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks.
(First I'd have liked to use the `-s` option, but that doesn't seem to exist on Linux.)

Comment: Isn't it [*bad to use `which` to detect binaries*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/114900)?

Comment: I did the minus one for saying eval is evil. This is bash, not javascript. Catch phrases don't carry across programming languages.

Comment: except it's not available in OSX

Comment: Beautiful use of bash (2nd version) ! learned something new today.

Comment: about xdg-open and xdg-utils, isnt it only for debian or available for other linux distros too?

Comment: @DarthEgregious, Your downvote is misplaced. `eval` [is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/2417578) in shell scripts.

Comment: `xdg-open` also works in a Linux distro on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I tested `xdg-open .` with Ubuntu 20.04 as the distro, and it opened the folder in the Windows File Explorer. From there it was easy to use the default web browser to load the HTML files that I happened to have in that directory.

Answer (score 115):

```bash
python -m webbrowser http://example.com
```

works on many platforms

Comment: If the user has Python installed... But thanks for mentioning the `webbrowser` module !

Comment: @JulienNicoulaud I just installed debian and python is there. I think it's bundled with many linux distributions.

Comment: It's a nice module, but it doesn't seem to work with local files.  This would be a common use case when doing web development.

Comment: @Hexatonic: It does work with local files e.g., `python -m webbrowser file:///usr/share/doc/python/FAQ.html`

Answer (score 63):

#### OSX:

```
$ open -a /Applications/Safari.app http://www.google.com
```

or

```
$ open -a /Applications/Firefox.app http://www.google.com
```

or simply...

```
$ open some_url
```

Comment: That's hardly very portable, either, but yes, that 's how you do it on OSX.

Comment: The question says "on most platforms"!

Comment: Some of us are using OSX, so this answer is useful.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the following:

```
x-www-browser
```

It won't run the user's but rather the system's default X browser.

See: [this thread.](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-programming-scripting/133128-calling-default-browser-bash.html)

Comment: `x-www-browser <url>` does the job very well!

Comment: Doesn't exist in Mac OS.

Comment: Lol, I just came here to comment on this and saw that my previous self had commented on it last year. This is some matrix / inception stuff.

Comment: works very well on WSL2 and opens the default windows browser

Answer (score 1):

Taking the other answers and making a version that works for all major OS's as well as checking to ensure that a URL is passed in as a run-time variable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "Must run command with the url you want to visit."
  exit 1
else
  URL=$1
fi
[[ -x $BROWSER ]] && exec "$BROWSER" "$URL"
path=$(which xdg-open || which gnome-open) && exec "$path" "$URL"
if open -Ra "safari" ; then
  echo "VERIFIED: 'Safari' is installed, opening browser..."
  open -a safari "$URL"
else
  echo "Can't find any browser"
fi
```

Answer (score -9):

This may not apply exactly to what you want to do, but there is a really easy way to create and launch a server using the [`http-server` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Once installed (just `npm install http-server -g`) you can put

`http-server -o`

in your bash script and it will launch a server from the current directory and open a browser to that page.

Comment: This requires `npm` to be installed + `http-server` package + launches an unneeded web server...

Comment: If you're going to use npm, there's a package called `open`, but it's still overkill