# Python. How to print text to console as hyperlink?

Tags: python, hyperlink, console-application

I'm working on a console application. My application uses [urwid](http://urwid.org/) lib. In some cases, I need to show very long hyperlinks as short text inside table columns. I want to open links in the browser when I click on the text inside the column.

So, my question is:

**It is possible to print text as a hyperlink to the console?**

Can you provide a small example of how to print text as a hyperlink using python?

Comment: That depends on your console, it has nothing to do with Python. FWIW, konsole, the standard KDE console, supports hyperlinks. If you print a URL to the console, it will get underlined if you hover over it, and if you right-click on it a menu pops up, and one of the menu options is "Open link".

Comment: You just print it syntactically correct. To identify the hyperlink is the job of the terminal application.

Comment: I tried in xubuntu terminal. The link can be opened by right-clicking the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using some tools, like gNewt or Curses, you could create a button and 'on click' do an action (like open a browser to a given url).

gNewt : http://gnewt.sourceforge.net/

nCurses : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/curses.html

Otherwise, it's the terminal application that will manage the text you give it, and if it doesn't implement uri's recognition your program won't work as you'd like.

Comment: It should be!
Using widgets : http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html
see `set_text()` and `mouse_event()`

Comment: Did gNewt get a new website? The sourceforge link is broken.

Answer (score 15):

A bit late, but there totally is a way to do that now, without curses or anything, just pure text and collaboration from your terminal emulator.

```
def link(uri, label=None):
    if label is None: 
        label = uri
    parameters = ''

    # OSC 8 ; params ; URI ST <name> OSC 8 ;; ST 
    escape_mask = '\033]8;{};{}\033\\{}\033]8;;\033\\'

    return escape_mask.format(parameters, uri, label)
```

Call that function with `link('https://example.com/')` to get a simple, clickable link, or `link('https://example.com/', 'example')` for a custom label.

Note that links are faintly underlined in your terminal, and not all of them support the feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, some consoles do recognize urls and convert them to a clickable hyperlink. All you can do is make it easy to recognize for console applications by putting a http:// in your url.

Also see
[How does bash recognize a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175313/how-does-bash-recognize-a-link)