# How do we create hyperlinked strings in Python? Is there a way?

Tags: python, pandas, hyperlink, nltk, sklearn-pandas

I am building a chatbot using nltk.util pairs. I am using regular expressions for the combinations! I want one of the responses to be “ Visit Google” where “Google” should be a hyperlink that should take you to https://www.google.com!

Comment: What do you mean by "hyperlinked strings"?

Comment: A clickable string! When you click on a string it has to navigate to a specified website!

Comment: In what will you be showing the hyperlink? A console (`print(hyperlink_str)`)? A GUI?

Comment: In a console!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40419276/10475068

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what media you are showing this hyperlink. You must format the output corresponding to this

For example, if it's in web page (and the page allows it), you can return a "" link

If it's in a cli, you probably won't be able with the standard interface of the OS.