# Get output text as link in python

Tags: python, output, clickable

Can someone help me to print the python output as link but it should display the customized text.

```
text = "Bug"
url = https://bug.com
```

i want to display Bug as output, but we click it should redirect to https://bug.com

I'm looking something similar to html anchor tag in python.

```
<a href = "https://bug.com" >Bug<a>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could maybe take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452410/creating-hyperlinks-in-python)

Comment: Where are you expecting the python output? In a console as a hyperlink? Maybe this [helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419276/python-how-to-print-text-to-console-as-hyperlink)