# Shell script to open a URL

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a simple shell script (say script.sh), so that I can pass a URL as an argument while executing?

I want a browser to start with the page opened on that URL. I want to write the command in the script to open a browser and open the URL given in argument.

Comment: I would update the question title to "Write a shell script to open a URL in a browser on Linux"

Comment: if you want a python solution, have a look at `webbrowser.open`. In a cli environment, you can just do `python -m webbrowser https://google.com`, provided you have python installed (most linux distributions do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean way to launch the web browser from shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124556/clean-way-to-launch-the-web-browser-from-shell-script)

Comment: `open http://localhost:9000`

Comment: IIRC, the `open` command is mac-only. It for sure doesn't work on ubuntu.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Method 1**

Suppose your browser is Firefox and your script `urlopener` is

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox "$1"
```

Run it like

```
./urlopener "https://google.com"
```

---

**Sidenote**

Replace `firefox` with your browser's executable file name.

---

**Method 2**

As [[ @sato-katsura ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4959010/sato-katsura) mentioned in the comment, in *nixes you can use an application called `xdg-open`. For example,

```
xdg-open https://google.com
```

The manual for `xdg-open` says

> xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
>   xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>   browser. 
>  
>   If a file is provided the file will be opened in the
>   preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file,
>   ftp, http and https URLs.

As [[ this ]](https://askubuntu.com/a/274586/344764) answer points out you could change your preferred browser using say:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

or

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

Comment: On UNIX: `xdg-open "$@"`

Comment: but can we do something so that I can run it like ...

urlopener google.com

Comment: can we run that script like a command...without using "./" in the beginning and without using double quotes in giving URL.

Comment: For that the path to your script should be added to the `PATH` environment variable. Check [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/1620779) Or copy the script to a standard binary folder though it is not the recommended method.

Comment: is it a good practice to add my script file in /usr/bin/ folder??

Comment: Can create another PATH environment variable?.. If I do so, won't it affect the execution of other commands?

Comment: You can't create another PATH environment variable. To add a new path to the existing path, the procedure is `PATH=$PATH:/your/new/path`

Comment: You might get a warning about `xdg-open` being deprecated in GNOME 3. in that case, use `gio open "$@"`. Both tools work exactly the same :)

Answer (score 154):

You don't need to write a script for that. There're some tools that you can use depending on your OS:

### Linux

`xdg-open` is available in most Linux distributions. It opens a file or URL in the user's preferred browser (configurable with `xdg-settings`).

```
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
```

### macOS

`open` opens files and URLs in the default or specified application.

```
open https://stackoverflow.com
open -a Firefox https://stackoverflow.com
```

### Windows

You can use the `start` command at the command prompt to open an URL in the default (or specified) browser.

```
start https://stackoverflow.com
start firefox https://stackoverflow.com
```

### Cross-platform

The builtin `webbrowser` Python module works on many platforms.

`python3 -m webbrowser https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Any way to tell it which browser to try first, eg Chrome. On Mac it tries firefox then falls back to safari

Comment: If I type "open stackoverflow.com", then it uses my default browser

Comment: Thanks for this solution, now i can put this in auto start script and make sure that every time I start my PC It will open stackoverflow first and hopefully in 100 day I will get a golden badge :)

Comment: for google chrome it is: open -a 'google chrome' _yoururl_

Comment: `python` is no longer cross-platform. Ubuntu 16.04 and above doesn't ship with Python 2 so it exits with `Command 'python' not found`

Comment: @Alex try this: `python3 -m webbrowser https://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 12):

For **Windows**,

You can just write `start filename_or_URL`

```
start https://www.google.com
```

It will open the URL in a default browser. If you want to specify the browser you can write:

```
start chrome https://www.google.com
start firefox https://www.google.com
start iexplore https://www.google.com
```

**Note:** The browser name above can be obtained from the `exe` file found in program files (sample: `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`) if you wish to open multiple URLs.

```
start chrome "www.google.com" "www.bing.com"
```

It was tested with .sh (shellscript file) and .bat files.

Answer (score 8):

In MacOS, just `open` works. So, `open "$1"` will open the passed URL in Chrome, if Chrome is the default browser.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a cross-OS solution and are comfortable using Python (3):

Try this:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://yoururl.com')
```

Or in a terminal/cmd:

```
python -m webbrowser -t "https://yoururl.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Cygwin under Windows** you can't use start. But you can use cygstart:

```
cygstart https://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

#### January 2021: Huge script for Aliases!

Here is an awesome [script](https://github.com/computingfoundation/gnu-linux-shell-scripting.packaged-solutions/tree/master/url_management/url_parsing_and_opening//openurl#openurl) for opening URLs with support for aliases and multiple browsers. Examples:

```
search|s|google|g
http://www.google.com/search?q={search\+}

search2|s2|yahoo
https://search.yahoo.com/search?p={search\+}

images|img
https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&q={search\+}

videos|v|youtube|yt
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={search\+}
```

To use the Google aliased URL, you just run:

```
openurl search how to make fried rice
```

This will parse the "google" URL and open

`https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+fried+rice`

See all the configuration options in the [project](https://github.com/computingfoundation/gnu-linux-shell-scripting.packaged-solutions/tree/master/url_management/url_parsing_and_opening//openurl#openurl)!

***Please note:** This repository has zero very few stars, only because it's a subrepository of a parent repository: [gnu-linux-shell-scripting](https://github.com/computingfoundation/gnu-linux-shell-scripting).*

Answer (score -4):

```
start "" "browser_location" "address"
```

For example:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com"
```

Comment: This is not a shell script. There are other answers here which include the same information but which correctly label it as a Windows-only variation and not actually an answer to the question at the top of this page.

Comment: this is batch for ```dos cmd``` not bash script.