# print string on a browser, shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I can't find a command to print on a browser a string in a shell script. For example here on stackoverflow. I'd like to create a script that writes a string in the searchbar and search

```
xdotool mousemove x y # position of the searchbar
xdotool mouseclick 1 # leftclick
[[command that writes a string on the searchbar]]
xdotool key KP_Enter # press enter
```

It should be easy but I can't find it

Comment: You can't simply write text on top of where the search bar is and expect it to be passed to the browser; you need a tool that can interact programmatically with the browser, or at least with the window manager. `bash` is neither.

Comment: @chepner there's a workaround of sorts that accomplishes most (if not all) of what is asked on the question. Check my answer (comments welcome).

Answer (score 0):

There might be an approximate way to do what you want (tested in Linux Debian 8). You could -- as a normal user, not root ([see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) for the reason) -- run the following command (on a terminal):

```
firefox "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=my_search_term"
```

That would open `firefox` on a Stack Overflow's page that would display the search results for the term `my_search_term`.

If you need this code to be run on a script that runs as `root`, it would still be possible to (safely) run this command if you run it as a "normal" user instead of `root`, such as:

```
su - myuser -c 'firefox "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=my_search_term"'
```

To find out who is the `user` who should be used to run the command above, one of the best options would be to use the `logname` command, such as:

```
myuser="$(logname 2>/dev/null)"
```

**Note**: This workaround of sorts would also works on many other web sites, such as Google, just substitute with the right `url` address, such as:

```
firefox "http://www.google.com/search?q=my_search_term"
```

Answer (score -1):

Would answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124556/clean-way-to-launch-the-web-browser-from-shell-script) be useful? Just replace url with apropriate search string *https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foobar*

Comment: If you're just going to link to another question, flag it as a duplicate.